# Can we view the Core data SQLite file from Oracle SQL Developer application in macOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, oracle-sqldeveloper, db-browser-sqlite

I am using Core data in my application. I want to view the actual Sqlite db file for verifying my data. I know about DBBrowser for SQLite but can I use Oracle SQLDeveloper for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Oracle SQL Developer has no support for SQLite.